# "Password Reset Mail" or "Reset Password Mail"?

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice

We are working on a web project that has a password reset feature.

Now the problem is, between "Password Reset Mail" and "Reset Password Mail", which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where that text belongs. If you have a button on a webpage to reset the password, it should simply say “Reset password by mail” or, shorter, “Mail password reset”. The mail itself would be a “Password reset email”.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean *email* instead of just *mail*, and that this is a link for resetting one's password, so I would suggest a couple of alternatives:

> Email Password Reset

which will be easily understood, or

> Reset Password Via Email

which is explicit.

Comment: Thanks, I mean which email title should I use?

Comment: Yes, and I'm suggesting that neither of your choices reflects optimal word order; hence, my offer of alternatives.

Comment: @Xhacker Liu: When talking about the email itself, you can say "Password reset email" (for instance, "The password reset email will arrive within two hours").